# Using jQuery sortable to rearrange table rows interferes with Angular orderBy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, jquery-ui

Originally I had a table in an angular app that would use orderBy to sort its rows based off the values in a certain column. If you clicked a table header, it would change the orderBy arguments and resort the list using the values in that column as criteria.

Now, I'm trying to use jQuery to let a user manually rearrange rows in the table. However, when they click the table header on the table after its rearranged, the rows would sort incorrectly. I'm assuming that something is not updating on the angular side that it can't see, but I can't find anything definite on it right now.

```
$('#game-table tbody').sortable({
   opacity: 0.5
});

<table id='game-table'>
  <thead>
       <th>
         <a class="sortable-link" ng-click="sortType = 'title; sortReverse = !sortReverse">  
         Titles
         </a>
       </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
       <tr class="game" ng-repeat="game in data | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse" style="cursor:move;">
```

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental difference between jQuery and Angular is that jQuery operates on the DOM, whereas Angular operates on raw data. When jQuery UI Sortable updates your table rows (through user interaction), Angular knows nothing of it. This breaks the association between Angular's data and the DOM representation of that data.

There is an [Angular UI Sortable directive on GitHub](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable) which you may find helpful. The purpose of the directive is to utilize jQuery UI Sortable functionality while mirroring the same changes in Angular's data.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciated learning why it happens as well.